# FullCalendar v2: Selecting day in month returns incorrect start or end date

Tags: fullcalendar

In version 1.x of FullCalendar, when **Tue**, Sept. 30th in the Month view was selected, the startDateTime would be something like "**Tue** Sep 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" and the endDateTime would be "**Tue** Sep 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)". This is good, it tells me that Tuesday September 30th 2014 was clicked and no time was specified by the user because they just clicked a day.

Now in version 2.1.1, when **Tue**, Sept. 30th in the Month view is selected, the start date is "**Mon** Sep 29 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" and the end date is "**Tue** Sep 30 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)".

The start date is incorrect because **Tuesday** was clicked, not **Monday**. As the day goes on, eventually the start date will be Tuesday and the end date will be Wednesday.

Is there an option (or workaround) I'm missing so that I can just get the **date** that was clicked in the month view and not this arbitrary span of time?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that replicates your issue?

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coderdave/cd78yybs/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of FullCalendar 2.*, [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is used to treat the dates.

Given this, `start` and `end` are momentjs objects. If you only want the date of the clicked day you can use:

```
console.log(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Here's the [**updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/cd78yybs/18/)

Comment: yes...but what if we need an end also at the SAME day.Meaning Sep 30th 10:30-11:00...is just changing the formatting string enough?

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou, yes, it's just a matter of formatting the string. You should notice, however, that getting the 'time' part only makes sense if you're in agendaWeek, for example. Check [**this jsfiddle fork**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/cd78yybs/24/).

Comment: Yes..but what if I want to display the time in month view too?The user must be able to see that too.Currently I can only depict the start time

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou Please ask a new question that states what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately my account is banned...I am still trying to lift the ban...anyway thanks

Comment: the only thing I want to add is that with this momentjs format,in weekview...the event is not rendered in the calendar,even if I refresh the page,in monthview there is no problem